# ElasticSearch Can't open file to read checksums

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch ran out of disk space on a couple nodes and this is the resulting error

The error we're getting is:

```
 [WARN][indices.store   ] [odr-es-md15] Can't open file to read checksums
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file [_2rlb_es090_0.pos]
at org.elasticsearch.index.store.DistributorDirectory.getDirectory(DistributorDirectory.java:176)
at org.elasticsearch.index.store.DistributorDirectory.getDirectory(DistributorDirectory.java:144)
at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$MetadataSnapshot.buildMetadata(Store.java:482)
at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$MetadataSnapshot.<init>(Store.java:456)
at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store.readMetadataSnapshot(Store.java:281)
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The translog may be corrupt.  I followed the directions from here:

http://unpunctualprogrammer.com/2014/05/13/corrupt-elasticsearch-translogs/

> To fix this you need to look in the ES Logs,
>   /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log for CentOS, and find the
>   error lines above. On those lines you’ll see something like
>
> ```
> [<timestamp>][WARN ][cluste.action.shard] [<wierd name>] [logstash-2014.05.13][X]
> ```
>
> where X (shard) is some number, likely (0,1,2,3,4), and the block
>   before that, logstash-date for me, and you if your doing centralized
>   logging like we are, is the index name. You then need to go to the
>   index location, /var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/
>   on centos. In that directory you’ll be able to find the following
>   structure, logstash-date/X/translog/translog-.
>   That’s the file you’ll need to delete, so:
>
> ```
> sudo service stop elasticsearch
> sudo rm /var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/logstash-date/X/translog/translog-blalblabla
> repeat step 2 for all indices and shards in the error log
> sudo service start elasticsearch
> ```
>
> Watch the logs and repeat that process as needed until the ES logs
>   stop spitting out stack traces.